# Python: Catch Exception inside Except Block

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to load a URL using selenium get function, sometime it does not loaded and I have to reload it again. I'm using this code,

```
       while flag:
           try:
               driver.get(url)
               EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))
               flag = False
           except:
               driver.get(url)
```

I can also get an exception inside except,
How to handle this?
One way is to add one more try-except inside except but I don't want to do this.
I want to keep trying unless link opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start with the Error you are getting.

Second, you are using while flag: so in the except you don't need to do much maybe just log the errors or count the attempts

Then you can use the errors to handle them:

```
while flag:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))
        flag = False
    except TimeoutException as t_e:
        print(t_e)
    except StaleElementReferenceException as s_e:
        print(s_e)
    except UnableToSetCookieException as u_e:
        print(u_e)
```

Comment: I'm getting timeout exception.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb you are using `while flag:` so in the `except` you don't need to do much maybe just log the errors or count the attempts.

Comment: Yes answer in your comment section worked for me. Please update it in Answer section so that I can upvote it.